# I can't uncheck "Manage Windows Without Launcher"

Tags: docky

Please help, I can't uncheck "Manage Windows Without Launcher" of the docky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Docky can have multiple docks, on the side, top or bottom of the screen, but it requires at least *one* of those docks to manage those windows that don't have a launcher on any dock. So you will have to select the dock you want to "Manage Windows Without Launcher" and check the box. Then when you select the dock that previously "Managed Windows Without Launcher" it will be unchecked.

Comment: its a shame, why would i want docky to manage the opened windows when i have panel. Going for cairo dock. thanks for the reply anyways.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this because I thought it was a bug.

This 'feature' + the 'no separator' politics answer I was given previously makes me wander if you want people to actually USE Docky or are you trying to send them all towards Cairo-dock??

Answer (score 1):

+ 1 for not wanting this behavior, otherwise Docky would have been perfect for me.

if you feel like me, go to bug [Bug #597755](https://bugs.launchpad.net/docky/+bug/597755) on launchpad and let the developers know you care by telling them this 'bug' also affects you or leaving a comment.