# Use Docky within Unity

Tags: unity, customization, docky, dock

I want to give Unity a try but still need some docklets that are provided by Docky, until Unity gets more flexible.

Is there a way to prevent Docky from managing windows without a launcher. Otherwise I have both, Unity and Docky, managing my open windows, which is a waste of space.

There has already been a question about unchecking the named option, what seems to be not possible by default: ["uncheck-manage-windows-without-launcher"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7093/i-cant-uncheck-manage-windows-without-launcher)

The answer was an explanation, why one of the docks in Docky does have to manage windows.

I am searching for a tweak, to change that behavior.
Since there is a tweak to hide the "Anchor-Icon" in Docky ["Remove Anchor in Docky"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4942/remove-the-anchor-icon-in-docky), maybe it is possible to hide Docky's "window-manager" as well.

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, you cannot stop Docky from using the window manager feature. The best you can do is find another Dock that allows you to do that.

Comment: That's not the answer I was actually hoping for, but thanks for your reply. I have switched to AWN and I do not regret it up to now. CU

Answer (score 1):

You could go to this site which I am sure will fix the problem.
It worked for me.
http://wiki.go-docky.com/index.php?title=Documentation
and click on **Super Secret GConf Settings** under Expert Settings and you will find that you can change the WindowManager from True to False

All the best
David